# Installing OpenAL (or a similar package) on W7

Tags: windows, haskell, openal

I want to install OpenAL Haskell bindings for Windows. When I try `cabal install alut` I get:

```
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring OpenAL-1.4.0.2...
cabal: The package has a './configure' script. This requires a Unix
compatibility toolchain such as MinGW+MSYS or Cygwin.
```

Installing MSYS or Cygwin is absolutely not an option. `runghc setup configure` on the source yields the same thing. This leads me to the following:

1. How can I install OpenAL with just an installation of the Haskell Platform? I know mingw comes with the Haskell Platform on Windows. Can I use just that to execute this script?
2. Is there a package that can play audio that installs with `cabal` on Windows 7 AND Unix based systems?
3. The source contains hundreds of directives designed for the configure script, which doesn't work on Windows. Is there a version of the source which is platform specific, ie, the script has already been run in a windows environment?

**Edit: Context for the problem:**
I have a Haskell program, which among other things, plays sound. It is going to be used for demonstration/interactive presentation to students. The computers in the lab run Windows 7. They have the Haskell Platform installed, but not MSYS or Cygwin. I have about 45 minutes to complete this, which doesn't leave time for the installation of needlessly complex and essentially pointless software. If I could get Windows-compatible source code, I could just distribute it with the program I wrote. All the packages I need besides this one will `cabal install` just fine; this is also a good introduction to package management.

Edit2: `cabal install` fails with Cygwin installed, as does `runghc setup configure`

Comment: "I don't want to install any of these so-called 'toolchains'." Why not? If you're working on Windows, they make your life much easier when communicating with the rest of the world.

Comment: You could run an .exe + .dlls from a Windows PC without MinGW/MSYS if you built it on a PC with MinGW/MSYS first.